# How to change this REGEX so it does NOT remove the colons :

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a `new Date().toISOString()` that returns something like this

```
2020-06-04T13:34:18.052Z
```

I need to go from there to `20200604-13:34:18.052` (if possible with nanosecond precision, else millisecond is ok, this is secondary)

I have this regex

```
new Date().toISOString().replace(/[^\d\.]/g,'').replace(/(^\d{8})/,'$1-')
```

Which is similar to what I need, but is removing the colons too, so I get

20200604-133418.051

Comment: Just add `:` in the character class `[^\d.:]`

Comment: Tank you @Toto, that did it, if you want to put as an answer I can accept. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `:` in the character class:

```
new Date().toISOString().replace(/[^\d:.]/g,'').replace(/(^\d{8})/,'$1-')
//                             here __^
```